# How do I make a test function for a class method?

Tags: function, unit-testing, class, testing, ode

I got this class, and I want to test the call method to see if the class is working properly. I'm implementing a test for testing that class Cooling
works. The test function should verify that the **call** method returns the
correct results for given values of the arguments T and t (the input into the call method is T and t) How would you solve it? With test function i mean with `def test_cooling():` My code is under:

```
class Cooling:
    def __init__(self,h,Ts):
        self.h=h
        self.Ts=Ts
        
    def __call__(self, T, t):
        self.T = T
        self.t = t
        h = -self.h*(self.T - self.Ts)
        self.T = (self.T) + self.t*h
        return self.T, self.t
```

I have tried with

```
def test_Cooling(self):
        c=Cooling()
        expected=c.__call__(T,t)
        self.assertTrue(expected, msg=None)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be no different than testing an object.

Comment: i have tried testing an object but it doesnt work properly

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far, please? [Edit it into your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64849174/edit).

Comment: Edited into my answer now

Answer (score 0):

To test something, you need to understand what it does.

`Cooling.__init__` takes two arguments. `c = Cooling(h, Ts)`.

[`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) should not be called explicitly. It instead lets you call an object like a function: `c(T, t)`. It returns the result of a calculation.

With that in mind, we can write a test to check that it returns what we expect.

You'd also need to test that h, Ts, T, and t are stored correctly. They're all just copies of the input except `self.T`.

```
class SampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Cooling(self):
        h = 1
        Ts = 2
        T = 3
        t = 4
        newT = -1
        expected = (newT,t)

        cooling = Cooling(h, Ts)
        self.assertEqual( cooling(T,t), expected )
        self.assertEqual( cooling.h, h )
        self.assertEqual( cooling.Ts, Ts )
        self.assertEqual( cooling.t, t )
        self.assertEqual( cooling.T, newT )
```

You'll have to pick a set of values for h, Ts, T, and t, and do the calculation for `newT` by hand. Or ask who wrote the function for some expected inputs and outputs.

Note that it returns `t` back unaltered, why is it returned at ll?

Comment: no, i need to make a function outside the class that tests the method, not inside the class

Comment: @TravisScott I don't understand. `test_Cooling` should not be inside the class. I've made it more clear.